# Google Chrome does not honor cache header when loading an audio source

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, audio

Google Chrome does not honor cache policy header when loading an audio source.

It does not ask the web server for cache freshness by GET request after getting the audio source for the first time. Even if I refresh the page, it stays the same. Only if I close the browser tab and re-open the page, it invokes the GET request. So I cannot change the server's audio file without also changing the file's URL. And cache-busting technique is too cost-ineffective for me.

Meanwhile, MS Edge does GET request. I think MS Edge's behavior is appropriate.

What's wrong? Can I tell Google Chrome to honor the cache policy?

The source code is as follows:

```
if (audio !== undefined)
    audio.pause();
audio = new Audio(webUrl + '/xxx/audioFile/' + name);
audio.play();
```

The response header is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 08:32:18 GMT
ETag: W/"77ffc-157adb89669"
Content-Type: audio/x-wav
Content-Range: bytes 0-491515/491516
Content-Length: 491516
Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 08:34:04 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```